# Coloring Intersection of Circles/Patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code:

```
# in ipython notebook, enable inline plotting with:
# %pylab inline --no-import-all
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create some circles
circle1 = plt.Circle((-.5,0), 1, color='r', alpha=.2)
circle2 = plt.Circle(( .5,0), 1, color='b', alpha=.2)

# add them to the plot (bad form to use ;, but saving space)
# and control the display a bit
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_artist(circle1); ax.add_artist(circle2)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2); ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# display it
plt.plot()
```

Produces the following plot:

[image: VennishDiagram]

I would like to specify the colors of the four regions (1) the background (currently white), (2 and 3) each individual event (the non-overlapping areas, currently blue and red), and (4) the intersection event (currently blended to purple).  For example, I might color them red, green, blue, yellow -or- I might give them four different, precisely specified grayscale values (the later is more likely).  [The colors will be generated based on characteristics of the underlying data.]

I specifically do not want to use alpha blending to "infer" a color in the intersection.  I need to explicitly control the colors of all four regions.

I can think of a few strategies to solve this:

- Ask mpl to extract the "primitive" patch objects that make up the three distinctly colored graphical regions (and do something similar to operate on the background) and then color them.
- Given the circles, manually compute their intersections and color that intersection (somehow).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think `matplotlib` does not have the functionality to intersect polygons. But you could use [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
import shapely.geometry as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import descartes

# create the circles with shapely
a = sg.Point(-.5,0).buffer(1.)
b = sg.Point(0.5,0).buffer(1.)

# compute the 3 parts
left = a.difference(b)
right = b.difference(a)
middle = a.intersection(b)

# use descartes to create the matplotlib patches
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(left, fc='b', ec='k', alpha=0.2))
ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(right, fc='r', ec='k', alpha=0.2))
ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(middle, fc='g', ec='k', alpha=0.2))

# control display
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2); ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's a great answer.  I'm going to hold off accepting to see if there's a reasonable "pure matplotlib" solution -- I'd prefer one dependency to three.  But, thanks for the pointers to shapely and descartes.

Comment: Ok, I'd be interested too and I understand your concern about dependencies. But I think you have to compute the intersections to generate 3 separate polygons (otherwise you would have to dig into the matplotlib backends and modify the rendering, I guess) and I'm quite sure that matplotlib does not have that functionality

Comment: So, I also realized that descartes is really only about 200 lines of code.  shapely looks like a really great tool:  http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#spatial-analysis-methods is the exact API I need right now.  I agree that matplotlib doesn't have that functionality exposed.  I wonder if any internal mpl functions do something similar.

Comment: So, I marked that answer as accepted because I doubt there is a pure matplotlib way (short of counting pixels manually) to achieve the same goal.  Since you might be interested, here's the project I used this for:  http://drsfenner.org/blog/2015/02/visualizing-probabilities-in-a-venn-diagram/

Comment: As of 15 APR 2023, this example code no longer compiles. Any updates / modifications now needed?